# CakePHP2.4 Login and Redirect doesn't work on server

Tags: cakephp, redirect, authentication

I'm using cakePHP building a website. The login function works fine in local, but after I post them onto the server, I cannot login with existing username and password. The page doesn't either let me log in, or give me an error message which is supposed to show up when there are issues. I tried almost every solution in stackoverflow but can't solve it. Here's my code.

Model:

```
class User extends AppModel {


public function beforeSave($options = array()) {

/* password hashing */    
if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
    $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data[$this->alias]['password']);
}
return true;
}
}
```

AppController:

```
class AppController extends Controller {

public function webroot() {

}

public $components = array('DebugKit.Toolbar','Session',
    /* add Auth component and set  the urls that will be loaded after the login and logout actions is performed */
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'Home', 'action' => 'index'),
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login')
    )
);

public function beforeFilter() {
    /* set actions that will not require login */
    $this->Auth->allow('index','display', 'view');
}

}
```

UsersController:

```
class UsersController extends AppController {

public $components = array('Auth');

public function beforeFilter() {
     parent::beforeFilter();
$this->Auth->allow('add', 'logout');
}

public function login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        /* login and redirect to url set in app controller */
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect('/Home'));
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
    }
}

public function logout() {
     /* logout and redirect to url set in app controller */
    return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
}
 public function index() {
    $this->User->recursive = 0;
    $this->set('Users', $this->paginate());
}

public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->User->create();
        if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash;
            return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'Home','action' => 'index'));
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
    }
}
}
```

View:

```
<?php echo $this->Session->flash('auth'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User'); ?>
<fieldset>
    <legend><?php echo __('Please enter your username and password'); ?></legend>
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('username');
    echo $this->Form->input('password');?>
</fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Login')); ?>
```

Another glitch I think I should mention is, as the code shows, when I add a new username and pw, the page should redirect me to Home. This also works fine locally, but on server it doesn't redirect, HOWEVER, the username and password is successfully stored into database when I added it. 
I'm really stuck and have no clue what the problem is, any help is appreciated, thanks.

---

Update

errors in error.log :

```
2014-05-14 05:16:21 Error: [MissingActionException] Action UsersController::js() could not be found.
Exception Attributes: array (
  'controller' => 'UsersController',
  'action' => 'js',
)
Request URL: /users/js/lightbox.min.js

2014-05-14 05:16:21 Error: [MissingActionException] Action UsersController::js() could not be found.
Exception Attributes: array (
  'controller' => 'UsersController',
  'action' => 'js',
)
Request URL: /users/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js
```

Comment: `The page doesn't [] give me an error message` your [setFlash](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/sessions.html#creating-notification-messages) calls and `Session->flash` calls are using different keys/elements - the default is `default`. `but on server it doesn't redirect` that probably indicates you have whitespace at the start of some file, and there is no session, and you can't redirect because "headers already sent" - check your `app/tmp/error.log` file. Also `public function webroot() {` <- wat?

Comment: Thank you for replay. I searched a lot of solution saying about white space, I did find some and I got rid of them, still not working. Also I checked error.log as you said, and I find this error occurs each time I click the login button:

2014-05-14 05:16:21 Error: [MissingActionException] Action UsersController::js() could not be found.
Exception Attributes: array (
  'controller' => 'UsersController',
  'action' => 'js',
)

Comment: It's too long so I edited in the post. Please check it.

Comment: The UsersController::js() or 'controller' => 'UsersController',
  'action' => 'js' is what I didn't even code in.. I'm totally lost.

Comment: `Request URL: /users/js/lightbox.min.js` <- `Request URL: /users/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js` <- you have requests for js files that don't exist; which in addition to meaning hte js won't work will probably invalidate the session.

Comment: That's where I feel so confused. I didn't request js in any function of Users...

Comment: Your server logs will show the referer - the url which made the request. Unfortunately it looks to me like SO isn't the right place for your doubts, there are many, possibly related but possibly not, problems - probably best to use the irc channel.